# How to retrieve contact numbers and save them?

Tags: contacts

I am developing an emergency Android application and I don't know how to retrieve contacts (for ex. 4) from the phone's catalogue firstly, and then save the selected in the app. database. Thus, whenever I want to send an emergency sms I don't have to retrieve contacts again or add any numbers. This is for an assignment so any ideas would be very useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at Contacts API in Android developers website?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't specify how to save them in the application database. Thank you though!